# How can I plot with DateListPlot data for the same month but different Year?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I have the following.

```
dataMarch2016 =incomeByDay[Select[
    DateValue[#Date, {"Year", "Month"}] == {2016, 3} &]]
```

[image: March 2016]

And the following.

```
dataMarch2017 =incomeByDay[Select[
    DateValue[#Date, {"Year", "Month"}] == {2017, 3} &]]
```

[image: March 2017]

The question is how can I plot both sets on the same plot such that each point on the horizontal axes be common to both lines? It would be nice if I can put an indicator on the peaks of the points to tell me how much March 2017 increased or decreased from March 2016.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First some fake data:

```
dates = With[{first = {2010, 1, 1}}, DateRange[first, DatePlus[first, {3, "Year"}]]];
values = 100 + RandomFunction[ARProcess[{0.7}, 1], {1, Length@dates}]["States"][[1]];
data = Transpose[{dates, values}];
months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
   "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

Organize the data using `GatherBy` (gather first by month and then by year), to generate some data with components similar to your `dataMarch2016` and `dataMarch2017`.

```
marchdata = {dataMarch2013, dataMarch2014, dataMarch2015} = 
   Select[GatherBy[data, {#[[1, 2]] &, #[[1, 1]] &}], #[[1, 1, 1, 2]] == 3 &][[1]];
```

Use the option setting `DateFunction :> (Join[{someyear}, #[[2 ;;]]] &)` for some arbitrary `someyear` to force `DateListPlot` to ignore different years in the data to be plotted:

```
DateListPlot[marchdata, Joined -> True, Filling -> Axis, 
 DateFunction :> (Join[{2000}, #[[2 ;;]]] &), 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"2013", "2014", "2015"}]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[md = Select[GatherBy[data, {#[[1, 2]] &, #[[1, 1]] &}], 
    #[[1, 1, 1, 2]] == month &][[1]];
  DateListPlot[md, Joined -> True, Filling -> Axis, 
    DateFunction :> (Join[{2000}, #[[2 ;;]]] &), 
    PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"2014", "2015", "2016"}]],
  {{month, 3, ""}, Thread[Range[12] -> months], ControlType -> SetterBar}, {md, None}]
```

[image]